# How can I limit my data usage over tethering on Windows?

Tags: windows, internet

The excess data charges if I go over my tethering data limit are ridiculously. Fennec already stated the question well.

> Because of this, and on general principle, I'd like to have some tools
>   which permit me to do things like:
>
> - Monitor the amount of bandwidth that I've used
>         I think I can do this from Sprint too, but on-the-computer is nice too
>         on-the-computer gives me a possibility of breaking it down by application
> - See what sort of programs are using the Internet connection
>         I could use, like, Wireshark, but that's a bit too micro-level to be practical
> - Keep those programs, and the operating system, from doing things like "downloading an operating system update" while on the mobile
>     hotspot

**Related**

[I want to monitor and limit OS X's data transfer while I'm tethering via my iPhone](https://superuser.com/questions/391406/i-want-to-monitor-and-limit-os-xs-data-transfer-while-im-tethering-via-my-ipho)

Comment: [Windows program to limit bandwidth of other programs?](http://superuser.com/questions/135719/windows-program-to-limit-bandwidth-of-other-programs)

Comment: [How to limit my Windows network transfer rate?](http://superuser.com/questions/309805/how-to-limit-my-windows-network-transfer-rate)